# url encoding in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Goodmorning.
Im working on MVC project with Angular and im using a JsonResult to return a Json from a list that i have with emails with the specific date.

Here is my ajax call from angular

```
myApp.service('mailService', function ($http) {
    this.getEmailByDate = function (date) {
        return $http.get("/Home/ShowEmailByDate/", { params: { date: date } });
    };
});
```

My JsonResult in Controller

```
public JsonResult ShowEmailByDate(string date)
{
    var selectedMsg = ClassHelper.listMsg;

    var result = selectedMsg.Select(s => new
    {
        From = s.From.RawValue,
        Date = s.Date.ToString("F"),
        searchDate = s.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        sortDate = s.Date.ToString("M"),
        sortTime = s.Date.ToString("t"),
        Subject = s.Subject,
        Body = s.BodyHtml,
        Attachments = s.AttachmentFiles.Count(),
        Files = s.AttachmentFiles.Select(f => f.FileName)
    })
    .Where(s => s.searchDate == date)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.sortDate)
    .ThenByDescending(s => s.sortTime);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now the problem that i have exists only in IE. On chrome and firefox is working fine. The link that i see in developer mode in Network tab when i execute the ajax call is like

```
htttp://localhost:0000/Home/ShowEmailByDate/?date=%E2%80%8E23%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E12%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E2015
```

So im getting an empty array result []

In Firefox and Chrome the link looks like

```
htttp://localhost:0000/Home/ShowEmailByDate/?date=22%2F12%2F2015 and its working fine.
```

the date param is a string like 22/12/2015 'dd/M/yyyy'

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You decode Url and then use it. because after decoding all output url of IE, chrome and firefox are same as you want.

Use **decodeURI()** function to decode a URI.

```js
var uri = "%E2%80%8E23%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E12%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E2015";
var dec = decodeURI(uri);
var res = "Decoded URI: " + dec;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I tried with decodeURIComponent and decodeURI but not worked. Can you give me an example on my code above how to do it?

Comment: when i am decode your url **"%E2%80%8E23%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E12%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E2015"** using **decodeURI** i get result as chrome and firefox url like this **23‎%2F‎12‎%2F‎2015**.

please check demo on [https://jsfiddle.net/oncm5r6e/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/oncm5r6e/3/)